# How to determine if a binary tree is balanced or not using recursion?

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I am trying to return true if the tree is balanced and false if not, I came up with this
recursive solution below but I am not correct the correct boolean. I feel that it makes
sense to compare the highest height of the tree vs the lower height? Not sure where I am going wrong

```
function tree (rootNode) {
  // Your code here
  if (!rootNode) return 0;
  if (!rootNode.left && !rootNode.right) return 0;
  let minHeigth = 1 + Math.min(tree(rootNode.left), tree(rootNode.right))
  let maxHeigth = 1 + Math.max(tree(rootNode.left), tree(rootNode.right))
  if(maxHeigth - minHeigth <= 1){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `Math.min` and `Math.max` on the result of two calls to `tree`, but `tree` only ever returns `0`, `true` or `false`. Wouldn't it need to return a numeric value for `minHeigth` and `maxHeigth` to be numeric?

Answer (score 0):

My recursive algorithm will be like this.

```
function isBalanced(rootNode){
  if(rootNode == null){
     return true;
   }
  if(checkHeight(rootNode) === -1){ 
    return false; 
  } else{
    return isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right);  
  }
}
```

and the helper method checkHeight which will check height will be

```
function checkHeight(rootNode){
  if(root ==null){
    return 0;
  }
  let leftHeight=checkHeight(root.left);
  let rightHeight=checkHeight(root.right);
  if(Math.abs(leftHeight - rightHeight) > 1){
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    return Math.max(leftHeight,rightHeight) +1;
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** This Algo will have the time complexity of O(N)

Comment: I guess whats confusing me with the recursion is how in your checkheight function is it counting the height without a counter? how does each recursive call on leftheight and rightheight adding up as a number to be subtracted and compared to 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that your function is mixing two things:

- Returning the height (number)
- Returning whether it is balanced (boolean)

If the ultimate purpose is to return a boolean, then you need a different function for getting the height (a number).

Secondly, in determining the height the first two lines of your code show an inconsistency:

- for a `null` (empty) tree it is determined that its height is 0
- for a node without children, it is also determined that its height is 0

Yet these two trees have a different height. If a single node (root) is considered to have height 0, then an empty tree has height -1. This is in line with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)):

> The height of a node is the length of the longest downward path to a leaf from that node. The height of the root is the height of the tree. The depth of a node is the length of the path to its root (i.e., its root path). This is commonly needed in the manipulation of the various self-balancing trees, AVL Trees in particular. The root node has depth zero, leaf nodes have height zero, and a tree with only a single node (hence both a root and leaf) has depth and height zero. Conventionally, an empty tree (tree with no nodes, if such are allowed) has height −1.